How can I reconstruct a function which skews the input to another function without knowing what either of them are?
Imagine I have a function $f(x)=g(x)$, which I am trying to reconstruct from two related functions, $f_1(x) = g(x + z(x))$ and $f_2(x) = g(x - \phi + z(x))$, where $\phi$ is a known constant and $z(x)$ is an unknown skew of the input. How can I reconstruct $f(x)$ while only knowing data points that follow $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, as well as the constant offset $\phi$?
This is the most abstract case of the problem that I'm trying to solve, so for some context, $g(x)$ will be roughly gaussian, $z(x)$ will be a smooth deviation from $y = 0$, and $z'(x)\ge0$. Like I mentioned above, I don't know any of the continuous forms of these functions. I just have data points which follow those curves. In addition, I don't need an analytic solution, an approximate solution will work fine, but an analytic solution would also work.

I'm sure the answer to the question in the first paragraph is that you can't. If you [edit] the question to describe your particular application in as much detail as possible there may be something we can say that will help.

There are a number of things about your post that are confusing. $f(x) = g(x)$. Why do you need two names for this function? Is there some importance to this? Does not the relationships between $f_1, f_2, g$ mean that $f_1(x) = f_2(x + \phi)$. so effectively you have only one function that you know? The other doesn't add any new informstion.

Turns out you can do this, it's quite simple. Divide phi by the difference in x-values between corresponding points on each curve that have the same y-value (some interpolation may be needed), and then integrate it and subtract the x-coordinate which that point came from. That gives you a very good approximation of what the function z(x) is.
